# How to add item into PagingListAdpter when scroll to last position

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

How to add new item also different ViewType and show it on recyclerView when user scroll to the last position?

[image]

I already fetch data from loadInitial and loadAfter.
But I wondered How to add new item when the API send me the last item?

For Example API send data size 50 and when user scroll to the position 49
I need to add the another one which is my custom ViewType into adapter and the size will be 51 position 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code 
It will work for you

```
class FollowFeedPagedListAdapter(val context: Context, val itemClicked: (FollowFeedModel) -> Unit) : PagedListAdapter<FollowFeedModel, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DIFF_COMPARATOR) {


val TYPE_NORMAL = 1
val TYPE_LAST_POSITION = 2

companion object {
    private val DIFF_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FollowFeedModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: FollowFeedModel, newItem: FollowFeedModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: FollowFeedModel, newItem: FollowFeedModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
    }

    private var hasMore: Boolean = true

    @JvmStatic
    fun getHasMoreInstance() = hasMore

    @JvmStatic
    fun setHasMoreInstance(boolean: Boolean) {
        hasMore = boolean

    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    val size = super.getItemCount()
    //เพิ่มอันสุดท้าย
    return size+1
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if (position == itemCount - 1) {
        return TYPE_LAST_POSITION
    } else {
        return TYPE_NORMAL
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    when (viewType) {
        TYPE_NORMAL -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_summaries_layout_version2, parent, false)
            return SummariesModelViewHolder(view, itemClicked)
        }
        TYPE_LAST_POSITION -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_no_more_follow_feed, parent, false)
            return NoMoreFollowFeedViewHolder(view)
        }
        else -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_no_more_follow_feed, parent, false)
            return SummariesModelViewHolder(view, itemClicked)
        }
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    when (holder.itemViewType) {
        TYPE_NORMAL -> {
            val holder = holder as SummariesModelViewHolder
            holder.binding(getItem(position))
        }
        TYPE_LAST_POSITION -> {
            val holder = holder as NoMoreFollowFeedViewHolder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

After loading 50 items from server (probably in 3 calls of 20+20+10)

Just generate/fetch items that you want to be displayed after 50th position,

Than return those generated/fetched items by calling:

'callback.onResult'